# Arquilian class not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to run a primitive EJB test(if it can be called a primitive) using Arquiliian(which I hate after spending 6 hours on it)

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class BookTest {
        @Deployment
        public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
            // explicit archive name required until ARQ-77 is resolved
            return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                    .addPackage(Book.class.getPackage())
                    .addPackage(BookEJB.class.getPackage())
                    .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
        }

        @EJB
        BookEJB bookEJB;

        @Test
        public void createAndFindBookByEjbTest() throws Exception {
            Book book = new Book("Cars", 10.0f, "The book of cars", "1-84023-742-2", 100, true);

            Book b = bookEJB.createBook(book);
            assertNotNull("ID should not be null", b.getId());

            assertNotNull(bookEJB.findBookById(b.getId()));
            assertEquals(1, bookEJB.findBooks().size());

        }
    }
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>
    <container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">/home/abondar/wildfly-11.0.0.Final</property>
            <property name="logThreshold">ERROR</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

        </arquillian>
```

And I get this stupid exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.abondar.experimetnal.javaeedemo.ejbdemo.test.BookTest from [Module
>   "deployment.test.war" from Service Module Loader]

How can I fix this crap?

Comment: Please add the content of your arquillian.xml file to your question

Comment: Here is the fix

Comment: Here is another working example if it helps you out: [arquillian-security-demo](https://github.com/sfcoy/demos/tree/master/arquillian-security-demo)

Comment: I don't understand why do I always have a WAR file to be deployed though I am trying to deploy a jar

Comment: Arquillian needs to include the code that runs your tests in the deployment, and it needs a way to communicate with it. It does this using a servlet.

Comment: Looks like I got closer to the solution. The problem is with adding persistence xml adn Book EJB which uses EntityManager. Persistence unit can't be found

Comment: `addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")`

Comment: There was a naming mismatch between EJB and xml. Looks like I need to replace RESOURCE_LOCAL to someting different

Comment: Yes - you would normally use a JTA DataSource. If you're feeling brave you could also have a look at my [jaxrs-people](https://github.com/sfcoy/jaxrs-people) example. This builds a test environment using Docker, in which the  Arquillian tests are executed.

Comment: Looks very interesting. Thanks a lot for sharing